# What is an Extended Stored Procedure in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005, database-administration, definition

What is an extended stored procedure in SQL Server?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Extended stored procedures are stored procedures that **call functions from DLL files**. You can read the article [How to use extended stored procedures](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190987) to learn more.

However, extended stored procedures are [**deprecated**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx) and you should avoid using them if possible. CLR Integration should be used instead.

Comment: +1 for Deprecated note and link, was asked in a skills matrix and I was like, I don't know of such things, are they new?  - LOL

Answer (score 2):

They reside inside the master database, you can use the command "sp_helpextendedproc", in respective database.

**See below screen shot:**

[image]