# Long delay executing stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

When I execute my SQL query against a database on server production (8 cores),it takes about 7 seconds to get 2244 rows.

I have an stored procedure with the same previous SQL query that when I execute it against my database, it takes about 1 minute and 20 seconds to get the same 2244 rows.

I have a table-value function with the same SQL query that when I execute it against my database, it takes about 1 minute and 20 seconds to get the same 2244 rows.

So:

SQL Query: 7 seconds

Stored procedure: 1 minute and 20 seconds.

Table-Value function: 1 minute and 20 seconds.

Now the weirdest part:

The same scenario on a test server (4 cores) with the same database, i get the following scores:

SQL Query: 1 minute and 20 seconds.

Stored procedure: 7 seconds.

Table-Value function: 7 seconds.

Is there something that I'm forgetting, which causes that long delay?

Comment: Could you please post your 2 stored procedures' queries into your question?

Comment: Hi @JohnOdom, as i explain, there is only one stored procedure. I can't post the SQL query because enterprise policies.

Comment: Hmm...Have you tried using CLR Integration instead? I just read from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603396/what-is-extended-stored-procedure-in-ms-sql-server) that extended stored procedures are deprecated and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Hi @JohnOdom again, sorry for that but i didn't know the difference about extended stored procedure and stored procedure until now. It is a stored procedure. I have edited the question. Thanks for that!

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up :). Try checking [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15262/why-does-a-query-run-slower-in-a-stored-procedure-than-in-the-query-window) to see if that helps. Maybe migrating your question to that site will help you get the answer you need faster, though this question now sounds more like a duplicate of the question in my link.

Comment: Thank you again @JohnOdom, it looks like it´s the same case, i will read the post and i will answer this post. :)

Comment: Sounds like parameter sniffing may be an issue. Try [one of the workarounds](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/turgays/archive/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-workarounds.aspx) to that issue.

Comment: My vote goes for parameter sniffing as well as @Mike suggest - usually gives that behaviour. Also try looking at this piece: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/high-performance-procedures/

Answer (score 4):

From my experience
 1) Try to put your parameter into local variable before use.

```
create procedure [dbo].[usp_test](@Id varchar(20))
as
begin
  select * from Test
  where Id = @Id
end
```

**to**

```
alter procedure [dbo].[usp_test](@Id varchar(20))
as
begin
  declare @local_id varchar(20) = @Id

  select * from Test
  where Id = @local_id
end
```

2) Use recompile hint. This will get new query plan which is more suitable for the query based on parameter value.

```
exec dbo.usp_test 1 with recompile
```

Ref
: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190439%28v=sql.105%29.aspx
: http://www.sqlpointers.com/2006/11/parameter-sniffing-stored-procedures.html

Comment: When I use option (recompile) directly on the SQL query, it takes 1 minute and 20 seconds on executing it. When I use the hint "with recompile" to the stored procedure, it keeps taking 1 minute and 20 seconds on executing it.
¿Could be the recompile action that do the long delay task?

Answer (score 1):

After long test and research, I really think this is a parameter sniffing problem, because I have done the following tests:

Execute SQL query normally: 7 seconds.

```
declare @field_1 int = 1
declare @field_2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = null
declare @field_3 NVARCHAR(MAX) = null
declare @field_4 NVARCHAR(MAX) = null
declare @field_5 NVARCHAR(MAX) = null
declare @field_6 NVARCHAR(MAX) = null
declare @field_7 NVARCHAR(MAX) = null
declare @field_8 DATE = dateadd(month, -1, getdate())
declare @field_9 DATE = getdate()
select * ...
```

Execute TVF like this: 7 seconds

```
declare @field_1 int = 1
declare @field_2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = null
declare @field_3 NVARCHAR(MAX) = null
declare @field_4 NVARCHAR(MAX) = null
declare @field_5 NVARCHAR(MAX) = null
declare @field_6 NVARCHAR(MAX) = null
declare @field_7 NVARCHAR(MAX) = null
declare @field_8 DATE = dateadd(month, -1, getdate())
declare @field_9 DATE = getdate()

select *
from fn_generar_reporte_cred(@field_1, @field_2, @field_3, @field_4, @field_5,
 @field_6, @field_7, @field_8, @field_9)
```

Execute TVF like this: 1 minute 20 seconds

```
select *
from fn_generar_reporte_cred(1, null, null, null, null, null, null, dateadd(month, -1, getdate()), getdate())
```

Execute SP normally: 1 minute 20 seconds

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pa_reporte_cred](
    @field_1 INT,
    @field_2 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @field_3 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @field_4 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @field_5 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @field_6 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @field_7 NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @field_8 DATE,
    @field_9 DATE
) AS
BEGIN
SELECT * ...
```

Execute SP normally (with inside changed): 7 seconds

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pa_reporte_cred_ss](
    @field_1_ss INT,
    @field_2_ss NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @field_3_ss NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @field_4_ss NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @field_5_ss NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @field_6_ss NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @field_7_ss NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @field_8_ss DATE,
    @field_9_ss DATE
) AS
BEGIN
declare @field_1 int
declare @field_2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
declare @field_3 NVARCHAR(MAX)
declare @field_4 NVARCHAR(MAX)
declare @field_5 NVARCHAR(MAX)
declare @field_6 NVARCHAR(MAX)
declare @field_7 NVARCHAR(MAX)
declare @field_8 DATE
declare @field_9 DATE
SELECT @field_1 = @field_1_ss, @field_2 = @field_2_ss, @field_3 = @field_3_ss,
    @field_4 = @field_4_ss, @field_5 = @field_5_ss, @field_6 = @field_6_ss,
    @field_7 = @field_7_ss, @field_8 = @field_8_ss, @field_9 = @field_9_ss
SELECT * ...
```

Thank you all for your help!