# Reduce SQL query execution time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, crystal-reports

I have a situation where our web application generates a Crystal Report based on the query result which takes almost 1 hr to execute.

I know this is crazy but, can anyone suggest any optimization or changes in the following giant query.

Thanks.

Note: I have shorten some of the similar queries.

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[sp_ExportRevenueMenifest_27FEB] 
   (@vessel varchar(10), @voyage varchar(10),
    @call varchar(10), @GLC varchar(10),
    @Port varchar(10), @str varchar(200)) 
AS 
   create table #OCF (PortCode varchar(10), 
                      PortName varchar(40),
                      BLNumber varchar(20), RS decimal(18,4),
                      RS1 decimal(18,4), Consignee varchar(500),
                      NoPackages varchar(50), Vessel varchar(10),
                      Vayage varchar(10), Call char(2),
                      Vessel_Name varchar(50),
                      Sailed_Date varchar(20), ExRate decimal(8,4)
                     )
insert into #OCF 
SELECT     a.PortofDischarge, Port_Master.Port_Name, a.BLNumber, SUM(B.PrepaidAmtUSD) AS PrepaidAmtUSD,SUM(B.COLLECTAmtUSD) AS COLLECTAmtUSD, a.Consignee, a.NoPackages, a.Vessel, 
                      a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.ExchangeRate
FROM         BLMaster a INNER JOIN
                      BL_ChargesDetails B ON a.BLID = B.BLID INNER JOIN
                      ExportVoyage_Master ON a.Vessel = ExportVoyage_Master.Vessel_Code AND a.Voyage = ExportVoyage_Master.Voyage_Code AND 
                      a.Port = ExportVoyage_Master.Port AND a.Call = ExportVoyage_Master.Call INNER JOIN
                      Vessel_Master ON ExportVoyage_Master.Vessel_Code = Vessel_Master.Vessel_Code INNER JOIN
                      Port_Master ON a.PortofDischarge = Port_Master.Port_Code
WHERE     (a.ImportExport = 2) AND (B.ConfigCode = 'OCF')
GROUP BY Port_Master.Port_Name, a.BLNumber, a.Consignee, a.NoPackages, a.Vessel, a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, 
                      ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.PortofDischarge, a.ExchangeRate, B.ConfigCode


create table #DDC (PortCode varchar(10), PortName varchar(40),BLNumber varchar(20), RS decimal(18,4),RS1 decimal(18,4),Consignee varchar(500),NoPackages varchar(50),Vessel varchar(10),Vayage varchar(10),Call char(2),Vessel_Name varchar(50),Sailed_Date varchar(20),ExRate decimal(8,4))
insert into #DDC 
SELECT     a.PortofDischarge, Port_Master.Port_Name, a.BLNumber, SUM(B.PrepaidAmtUSD) AS PrepaidAmtUSD,SUM(B.COLLECTAmtUSD) AS COLLECTAmtUSD, a.Consignee, a.NoPackages, a.Vessel, 
                      a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.ExchangeRate
FROM         BLMaster a INNER JOIN
                      BL_ChargesDetails B ON a.BLID = B.BLID INNER JOIN
                      ExportVoyage_Master ON a.Vessel = ExportVoyage_Master.Vessel_Code AND a.Voyage = ExportVoyage_Master.Voyage_Code AND 
                      a.Port = ExportVoyage_Master.Port AND a.Call = ExportVoyage_Master.Call INNER JOIN
                      Vessel_Master ON ExportVoyage_Master.Vessel_Code = Vessel_Master.Vessel_Code INNER JOIN
                      Port_Master ON a.PortofDischarge = Port_Master.Port_Code
WHERE     (a.ImportExport = 2) AND (B.ConfigCode = 'DDC')
GROUP BY Port_Master.Port_Name, a.BLNumber, a.Consignee, a.NoPackages, a.Vessel, a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, 
                      ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.PortofDischarge, a.ExchangeRate, B.ConfigCode

create table #FUM (PortCode varchar(10), PortName varchar(40),BLNumber varchar(20), RS decimal(18,4),RS1 decimal(18,4),Consignee varchar(500),NoPackages varchar(50),Vessel varchar(10),Vayage varchar(10),Call char(2),Vessel_Name varchar(50),Sailed_Date varchar(20),ExRate decimal(8,4))
insert into #FUM
SELECT     a.PortofDischarge, ....., a.Vessel, 
                      a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.ExchangeRate
FROM         BLMaster a INNER JOIN
                      BL_ChargesDetails B ON a.BLID = B.BLID INNER JOIN
                      ....INNER JOIN
                      Port_Master ON a.PortofDischarge = Port_Master.Port_Code
WHERE     (a.ImportExport = 2) AND (B.ConfigCode = 'FUM')
GROUP BY Port_Master.Port_Name,.... B.ConfigCode


create table #PSS (PortCode varchar(10), PortName varchar(40),BLNumber varchar(20), RS decimal(18,4),RS1 decimal(18,4),Consignee varchar(500),NoPackages varchar(50),Vessel varchar(10),Vayage varchar(10),Call char(2),Vessel_Name varchar(50),Sailed_Date varchar(20),ExRate decimal(8,4))
insert into #PSS
SELECT     a.PortofDischarge, .... a.ExchangeRate
FROM         BLMaster a INNER JOIN
                      BL_ChargesDetails B ON a.BLID = B.BLID INNER JOIN
                      ExportVoyage_Master ON a.Vessel = ExportVoyage_Master.Vessel_Code AND a.Voyage = ExportVoyage_Master.Voyage_Code AND 
                      a.Port = ExportVoyage_Master.Port AND a.Call = ExportVoyage_Master.Call INNER JOIN
                      Vessel_Master ON ExportVoyage_Master.Vessel_Code = Vessel_Master.Vessel_Code INNER JOIN
                      Port_Master ON a.PortofDischarge = Port_Master.Port_Code
WHERE     (a.ImportExport = 2) AND (B.ConfigCode = 'PSS')
GROUP BY Port_Master.Port_Name, ....., B.ConfigCode


create table #BAF (PortCode varchar(10), PortName varchar(40),BLNumber varchar(20), RS decimal(18,4),RS1 decimal(18,4),Consignee varchar(500),NoPackages varchar(50),Vessel varchar(10),Vayage varchar(10),Call char(2),Vessel_Name varchar(50),Sailed_Date varchar(20),ExRate decimal(8,4))
insert into #BAF
SELECT     a.PortofDischarge, .... a.Vessel, 
                      a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.ExchangeRate
FROM         BLMaster a INNER JOIN
                      BL_ChargesDetails B ON a.BLID = B.BLID INNER JOIN
                      ...... ON a.PortofDischarge = Port_Master.Port_Code
WHERE     (a.ImportExport = 2) AND (B.ConfigCode = 'BAF')
GROUP BY Port_Master.Port_Name, ..... B.ConfigCode


create table #HD (PortCode varchar(10), PortName varchar(40),BLNumber varchar(20), RS decimal(18,4),RS1 decimal(18,4),Consignee varchar(500),NoPackages varchar(50),Vessel varchar(10),Vayage varchar(10),Call char(2),Vessel_Name varchar(50),Sailed_Date varchar(20),ExRate decimal(8,4))
insert into #HD
SELECT     a.PortofDischarge, ..... a.Vessel, 
                      a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.ExchangeRate
FROM         BLMaster a INNER JOIN

                      BL_ChargesDetails B ON a.BLID = B.BLID INNER JOIN
                      ExportVoyage_Master ON a.Vessel = ExportVoyage_Master.Vessel_Code AND a.Voyage = ExportVoyage_Master.Voyage_Code AND 
                      ...... ON a.PortofDischarge = Port_Master.Port_Code
WHERE     (a.ImportExport = 2) AND (B.ConfigCode = 'HD')
GROUP BY Port_Master.Port_Name, ..... B.ConfigCode

create table #WRS (PortCode varchar(10), PortName varchar(40),BLNumber varchar(20), RS decimal(18,4),RS1 decimal(18,4),Consignee varchar(500),NoPackages varchar(50),Vessel varchar(10),Vayage varchar(10),Call char(2),Vessel_Name varchar(50),Sailed_Date varchar(20),ExRate decimal(8,4))
insert into #WRS
SELECT     a.PortofDischarge, Port_Master.Port_Name, a.BLNumber, SUM(B.PrepaidAmtUSD) AS PrepaidAmtUSD,SUM(B.COLLECTAmtUSD) AS COLLECTAmtUSD, a.Consignee, a.NoPackages, a.Vessel, 
                      a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.ExchangeRate
FROM         BLMaster a INNER JOIN
                      BL_ChargesDetails B ON a.BLID = B.BLID INNER JOIN
                      ExportVoyage_Master ON a.Vessel = ExportVoyage_Master.Vessel_Code AND a.Voyage = ExportVoyage_Master.Voyage_Code AND 
                      a.Port = ExportVoyage_Master.Port AND a.Call = ExportVoyage_Master.Call INNER JOIN
                      Vessel_Master ON ExportVoyage_Master.Vessel_Code = Vessel_Master.Vessel_Code INNER JOIN
                      Port_Master ON a.PortofDischarge = Port_Master.Port_Code
WHERE     (a.ImportExport = 2) AND (B.ConfigCode = 'WRS')
GROUP BY Port_Master.Port_Name, a.BLNumber, a.Consignee, a.NoPackages, a.Vessel, a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, 
                      ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.PortofDischarge, a.ExchangeRate, B.ConfigCode


create table #DIV (PortCode varchar(10), PortName varchar(40),BLNumber varchar(20), RS decimal(18,4),RS1 decimal(18,4),Consignee varchar(500),NoPackages varchar(50),Vessel varchar(10),Vayage varchar(10),Call char(2),Vessel_Name varchar(50),Sailed_Date varchar(20),ExRate decimal(8,4))
insert into #DIV
SELECT     a.PortofDischarge, Port_Master.Port_Name, a.BLNumber, SUM(B.PrepaidAmtUSD) AS PrepaidAmtUSD,SUM(B.COLLECTAmtUSD) AS COLLECTAmtUSD, a.Consignee, a.NoPackages, a.Vessel, 
                      a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.ExchangeRate
FROM         BLMaster a INNER JOIN
                      BL_ChargesDetails B ON a.BLID = B.BLID INNER JOIN
                      ExportVoyage_Master ON a.Vessel = ExportVoyage_Master.Vessel_Code AND a.Voyage = ExportVoyage_Master.Voyage_Code AND 
                      a.Port = ExportVoyage_Master.Port AND a.Call = ExportVoyage_Master.Call INNER JOIN
                      Vessel_Master ON ExportVoyage_Master.Vessel_Code = Vessel_Master.Vessel_Code INNER JOIN
                      Port_Master ON a.PortofDischarge = Port_Master.Port_Code
WHERE     (a.ImportExport = 2) AND (B.ConfigCode = 'DIV')
GROUP BY Port_Master.Port_Name, a.BLNumber, a.Consignee, a.NoPackages, a.Vessel, a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, 
                      ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.PortofDischarge, a.ExchangeRate, B.ConfigCode

create table #PAN (PortCode varchar(10), PortName varchar(40),BLNumber varchar(20), RS decimal(18,4),RS1 decimal(18,4),Consignee varchar(500),NoPackages varchar(50),Vessel varchar(10),Vayage varchar(10),Call char(2),Vessel_Name varchar(50),Sailed_Date varchar(20),ExRate decimal(8,4))
insert into #PAN
SELECT     a.PortofDischarge, Port_Master.Port_Name, a.BLNumber, SUM(B.PrepaidAmtUSD) AS PrepaidAmtUSD,SUM(B.COLLECTAmtUSD) AS COLLECTAmtUSD, a.Consignee, a.NoPackages, a.Vessel, 
                      a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.ExchangeRate
FROM         BLMaster a INNER JOIN
                      BL_ChargesDetails B ON a.BLID = B.BLID INNER JOIN
                      ExportVoyage_Master ON a.Vessel = ExportVoyage_Master.Vessel_Code AND a.Voyage = ExportVoyage_Master.Voyage_Code AND 
                      a.Port = ExportVoyage_Master.Port AND a.Call = ExportVoyage_Master.Call INNER JOIN
                      Vessel_Master ON ExportVoyage_Master.Vessel_Code = Vessel_Master.Vessel_Code INNER JOIN
                      Port_Master ON a.PortofDischarge = Port_Master.Port_Code
WHERE     (a.ImportExport = 2) AND (B.ConfigCode = 'PAN')
GROUP BY Port_Master.Port_Name, a.BLNumber, a.Consignee, a.NoPackages, a.Vessel, a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, 
                      ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.PortofDischarge, a.ExchangeRate, B.ConfigCode
create table #CAF (PortCode varchar(10), PortName varchar(40),BLNumber varchar(20), RS decimal(18,4),RS1 decimal(18,4),Consignee varchar(500),NoPackages varchar(50),Vessel varchar(10),Vayage varchar(10),Call char(2),Vessel_Name varchar(50),Sailed_Date varchar(20),ExRate decimal(8,4))
insert into #CAF
SELECT     a.PortofDischarge, Port_Master.Port_Name, a.BLNumber, SUM(B.PrepaidAmtUSD) AS PrepaidAmtUSD,SUM(B.COLLECTAmtUSD) AS COLLECTAmtUSD, a.Consignee, a.NoPackages, a.Vessel, 
                      a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.ExchangeRate
FROM         BLMaster a INNER JOIN
                      BL_ChargesDetails B ON a.BLID = B.BLID INNER JOIN
                      ExportVoyage_Master ON a.Vessel = ExportVoyage_Master.Vessel_Code AND a.Voyage = ExportVoyage_Master.Voyage_Code AND 
                      a.Port = ExportVoyage_Master.Port AND a.Call = ExportVoyage_Master.Call INNER JOIN
                      Vessel_Master ON ExportVoyage_Master.Vessel_Code = Vessel_Master.Vessel_Code INNER JOIN
                      Port_Master ON a.PortofDischarge = Port_Master.Port_Code
WHERE     (a.ImportExport = 2) AND (B.ConfigCode = 'CAF')
GROUP BY Port_Master.Port_Name, a.BLNumber, a.Consignee, a.NoPackages, a.Vessel, a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, 
                      ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.PortofDischarge, a.ExchangeRate, B.ConfigCode

create table #CDR (PortCode varchar(10), PortName varchar(40),BLNumber varchar(20), RS decimal(18,4),RS1 decimal(18,4),Consignee varchar(500),NoPackages varchar(50),Vessel varchar(10),Vayage varchar(10),Call char(2),Vessel_Name varchar(50),Sailed_Date varchar(20),ExRate decimal(8,4))
insert into #CDR
SELECT     a.PortofDischarge, Port_Master.Port_Name, a.BLNumber, SUM(B.PrepaidAmtUSD) AS PrepaidAmtUSD,SUM(B.COLLECTAmtUSD) AS COLLECTAmtUSD, a.Consignee, a.NoPackages, a.Vessel, 
                      a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.ExchangeRate
FROM         BLMaster a INNER JOIN
                      ..... ON a.PortofDischarge = Port_Master.Port_Code
WHERE     (a.ImportExport = 2) AND (B.ConfigCode = 'CDR')
GROUP BY Port_Master.Port_Name, .... B.ConfigCode

create table #THC (PortCode varchar(10), PortName varchar(40),BLNumber varchar(20), RS decimal(18),RS1 decimal(18),Consignee varchar(500),NoPackages varchar(50),Vessel varchar(10),Vayage varchar(10),Call char(2),Vessel_Name varchar(50),Sailed_Date varchar(20),ExRate decimal(8,4))
insert into #THC
SELECT     a.PortofDischarge, ......, a.Vessel, 
                      a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.ExchangeRate
FROM         BLMaster a INNER JOIN
                      BL_ChargesDetails B ON a.BLID = B.BLID INNER JOIN
                      ......
WHERE     (a.ImportExport = 2) AND (B.ConfigCode = 'THC')
GROUP BY Port_Master.Port_Name, a.BLNumber, a.Consignee, a.NoPackages, a.Vessel, a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, 
                      ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.PortofDischarge, a.ExchangeRate, B.ConfigCode

create table #INL (PortCode varchar(10),....,ExRate decimal(8,4))
insert into #INL
SELECT     a.PortofDischarge, Port_Master.Port_Name, a.BLNumber, SUM(B.PrepaidAmtRupee) AS PrepaidAmtRupee,SUM(B.CollectAmtRupee) AS collectAmtRupee, a.Consignee, a.NoPackages, a.Vessel, 
                      a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.ExchangeRate
FROM         BLMaster a INNER JOIN
                      ......
WHERE     (a.ImportExport = 2) AND (B.ConfigCode = 'INL')
GROUP BY Port_Master.Port_Name, ......, B.ConfigCode

create table #ARB (PortCode varchar(10), PortName varchar(40),BLNumber varchar(20), RS decimal(18,4),RS1 decimal(18,4),Consignee varchar(500),NoPackages varchar(50),Vessel varchar(10),Vayage varchar(10),Call char(2),Vessel_Name varchar(50),Sailed_Date varchar(20),ExRate decimal(8,4))
insert into #ARB
SELECT     a.PortofDischarge, Port_Master.Port_Name, a.BLNumber, SUM(B.PrepaidAmtRupee) AS PrepaidAmtRupee,SUM(B.CollectAmtRupee) AS collectAmtRupee, a.Consignee, a.NoPackages, a.Vessel, 
                      a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.ExchangeRate
FROM         BLMaster a INNER JOIN
                      BL_ChargesDetails B ON a.BLID = B.BLID INNER JOIN
                      ExportVoyage_Master ON a.Vessel = ExportVoyage_Master.Vessel_Code AND a.Voyage = ExportVoyage_Master.Voyage_Code AND 
                      a.Port = ExportVoyage_Master.Port AND a.Call = ExportVoyage_Master.Call INNER JOIN
                      Vessel_Master ON ExportVoyage_Master.Vessel_Code = Vessel_Master.Vessel_Code INNER JOIN
                      Port_Master ON a.PortofDischarge = Port_Master.Port_Code
WHERE     (a.ImportExport = 2) AND (B.ConfigCode = 'ARB')
GROUP BY Port_Master.Port_Name, a.BLNumber, a.Consignee, a.NoPackages, a.Vessel, a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, 
                      ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.PortofDischarge, a.ExchangeRate, B.ConfigCode


create table #DOC (PortCode varchar(10), PortName varchar(40),BLNumber varchar(20), RS decimal(18,4),RS1 decimal(18,4),Consignee varchar(500),NoPackages varchar(50),Vessel varchar(10),Vayage varchar(10),Call char(2),Vessel_Name varchar(50),Sailed_Date varchar(20),ExRate decimal(8,4))
insert into #DOC
SELECT     a.PortofDischarge, .... a.Vessel, 
                      a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.ExchangeRate
FROM         BLMaster a INNER JOIN
                      BL_ChargesDetails B ON a.BLID = B.BLID INNER JOIN
                      ExportVoyage_Master ON a.Vessel = ExportVoyage_Master.Vessel_Code AND a.Voyage = ExportVoyage_Master.Voyage_Code AND 
                      .... ON a.PortofDischarge = Port_Master.Port_Code
WHERE     (a.ImportExport = 2) AND (B.ConfigCode = 'DOC')
GROUP BY Port_Master.Port_Name, ...., B.ConfigCode


create table #THCUSD (PortCode varchar(10), PortName varchar(40),BLNumber varchar(20), RS decimal(18,4),RS1 decimal(18,4),Consignee varchar(500),NoPackages varchar(50),Vessel varchar(10),Vayage varchar(10),Call char(2),Vessel_Name varchar(50),Sailed_Date varchar(20),ExRate decimal(8,4))
insert into #THCUSD 
SELECT     a.PortofDischarge, .... a.Vessel, 
                      a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.ExchangeRate
FROM         BLMaster a INNER JOIN
                      BL_ChargesDetails B ON a.BLID = B.BLID INNER JOIN
                      ExportVoyage_Master ON a.Vessel = ExportVoyage_Master.Vessel_Code AND a.Voyage = ExportVoyage_Master.Voyage_Code AND 
                      .... ON a.PortofDischarge = Port_Master.Port_Code
WHERE     (a.ImportExport = 2) AND (b.ConfigCode='THC')
GROUP BY Port_Master.Port_Name,...., a.ExchangeRate


create table #INLUSD (PortCode varchar(10), PortName varchar(40),BLNumber varchar(20), RS decimal(18,4),RS1 decimal(18,4),Consignee varchar(500),NoPackages varchar(50),Vessel varchar(10),Vayage varchar(10),Call char(2),Vessel_Name varchar(50),Sailed_Date varchar(20),ExRate decimal(8,4))
insert into #INLUSD 
SELECT     a.PortofDischarge, .... a.Vessel, 
                      a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.ExchangeRate
FROM         BLMaster a INNER JOIN
                      BL_ChargesDetails B ON a.BLID = B.BLID INNER JOIN
                      ExportVoyage_Master ON a.Vessel = ExportVoyage_Master.Vessel_Code AND a.Voyage = ExportVoyage_Master.Voyage_Code AND 
                      .....ON a.PortofDischarge = Port_Master.Port_Code
WHERE     (a.ImportExport = 2) AND (b.ConfigCode='INL')
GROUP BY Port_Master.Port_Name,.... a.ExchangeRate

create table #ARBUSD (PortCode varchar(10), PortName varchar(40),BLNumber varchar(20), RS decimal(18,4),RS1 decimal(18,4),Consignee varchar(500),NoPackages varchar(50),Vessel varchar(10),Vayage varchar(10),Call char(2),Vessel_Name varchar(50),Sailed_Date varchar(20),ExRate decimal(8,4))
insert into #ARBUSD 
SELECT     a.PortofDischarge, ....., a.Vessel, 
                      a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.ExchangeRate
FROM         BLMaster a INNER JOIN
                      .....
                      Port_Master ON a.PortofDischarge = Port_Master.Port_Code
WHERE     (a.ImportExport = 2) AND (b.ConfigCode='ARB')
GROUP BY Port_Master.Port_Name,.... a.ExchangeRate


create table #OTH (PortCode varchar(10), PortName varchar(40),BLNumber varchar(20), RS decimal(18,4),RS1 decimal(18,4),Consignee varchar(500),NoPackages varchar(50),Vessel varchar(10),Vayage varchar(10),Call char(2),Vessel_Name varchar(50),Sailed_Date varchar(20),ExRate decimal(8,4))
insert into #OTH
SELECT     a.PortofDischarge, Port_Master.Port_Name, a.BLNumber, SUM(B.PrepaidAmtUSD) AS PrepaidAmtUSD,SUM(B.COLLECTAmtUSD) AS COLLECTAmtUSD, a.Consignee, a.NoPackages, a.Vessel, 
                      a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.ExchangeRate
FROM         BLMaster a INNER JOIN
                      BL_ChargesDetails B ON a.BLID = B.BLID INNER JOIN
                      ExportVoyage_Master ON a.Vessel = ExportVoyage_Master.Vessel_Code AND a.Voyage = ExportVoyage_Master.Voyage_Code AND 
                      a.Port = ExportVoyage_Master.Port AND a.Call = ExportVoyage_Master.Call INNER JOIN
                      Vessel_Master ON ExportVoyage_Master.Vessel_Code = Vessel_Master.Vessel_Code INNER JOIN
                      Port_Master ON a.PortofDischarge = Port_Master.Port_Code
WHERE     (a.ImportExport = 2) AND b.ConfigCode NOT IN('OCF','FUM','BAF','YAS','CAF','HD','DIV','PSS','CAF','PSS','PAN','WRS','CDR','THC','INL','DDC','ARB','DOC','STX')
GROUP BY Port_Master.Port_Name, a.BLNumber, a.Consignee, a.NoPackages, a.Vessel, a.Voyage, a.Call, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, 
                      ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, a.PortofDischarge, a.ExchangeRate



DECLARE @Query varchar(8000)
SET @Query = ''




SELECT @Query ='SELECT     Port_Master.Port_Name,Vessel_Master.Vessel_Name, Vessel_Master.Vessel_Code, ExportVoyage_Master.Voyage_Code, ExportVoyage_Master.Sailed_Date, 
                      Vessel_Master.Nationality, ExportVoyage_Master.Master, a.Portofloading,a.PortofDischarge,a.FinalDestination, ExportVoyage_Master.Call,ExportVoyage_Master.Berth_Date,a.BLNumber,a.Shipper, a.Consignee,a.port,
                      a.MarksNo, a.GoodsDescription, a.NoPackages, BL_ClubbedContainer.ContainerNo,   
                      BL_ClubbedContainer.TypeSize, A.ExchangeRate, a.BrokerCode,
                     isnull(OC.RS,0)OCF,isnull(FU.RS,0)FUM,isnull(BA.RS,0)BAF,isnull(CA.RS,0)CAF,isnull(HD.RS,0)HD,isnull(DI.RS,0)DIV,isnull(PS.RS,0)PSS,isnull(PA.RS,0)PAN,isnull(WR.RS,0)WRS,isnull(CD.RS,0)CDR,isnull(TH.RS,0)THC,isnull(DD.RS,0)DDC,isnull(INL.RS,0)INL,isnull(AR.RS,0)ARB,isnull(DO.RS,0)DOC,isnull(OT.RS,0)OTH,isnull(THUS.RS,0)THCUSD,isnull(INUS.RS,0)INLUSD,isnull(ARUS.RS,0)ARBUSD,isnull(OC.RS1,0)OCF1,isnull(FU.RS1,0)FUM1,isnull(BA.RS1,0)BAF1,isnull(CA.RS1,0)CAF1,isnull(HD.RS1,0)HD1,isnull(DI.RS1,0)DIV1,isnull(PS.RS1,0) PSS1,isnull(PA.RS1,0) PAN1,isnull(WR.RS1,0) WRS1,isnull(CD.RS1,0)CDR1,isnull(TH.RS1,0)THC1,isnull(DD.RS1,0)DDC1,isnull(INL.RS1,0)INL1,isnull(AR.RS1,0)ARB1,isnull(DO.RS1,0) DOC1,isnull(OT.RS1,0)OTH1,isnull(THUS.RS1,0)THCUSD1,isnull(INUS.RS1,0)INLUSD1,isnull(ARUS.RS1,0)ARBUSD1
FROM         BLMaster a LEFT OUTER JOIN

                     BL_ClubbedContainer ON a.BLNumber = BL_ClubbedContainer.BLNumber INNER JOIN
                      ExportVoyage_Master ON a.Vessel = ExportVoyage_Master.Vessel_Code AND a.Voyage = ExportVoyage_Master.Voyage_Code AND 
                      a.Port = ExportVoyage_Master.Port AND a.Call = ExportVoyage_Master.Call INNER JOIN
                      Vessel_Master ON ExportVoyage_Master.Vessel_Code = Vessel_Master.Vessel_Code inner join port_master on a.FinalDestination=Port_Master.Port_Code
left outer join #OCF OC on OC.blnumber=a.blnumber 
left outer join #DDC DD on DD.blnumber=a.blnumber 
left outer join #FUM FU on FU.blnumber=a.blnumber 
left outer join #BAF BA on BA.blnumber=a.blnumber 
left outer join #HD HD on HD.blnumber=a.blnumber 
left outer join #DIV DI on DI.blnumber=a.blnumber 
left outer join #WRS WR on WR.blnumber=a.blnumber 
left outer join #CAF CA on CA.blnumber=a.blnumber 
left outer join #PSS PS on PS.blnumber=a.blnumber 
left outer join #PAN PA on PA.blnumber=a.blnumber 
left outer join #CDR CD on CD.blnumber=a.blnumber 
left outer join #THC TH on TH.blnumber=a.blnumber 
left outer join #INL INL on INL.blnumber=a.blnumber 
left outer join #ARB AR on AR.blnumber=a.blnumber 
left outer join #DOC DO on DO.blnumber=a.blnumber 
left outer join #OTH OT on OT.blnumber=a.blnumber 
left outer join #THCUSD THUS on THUS.blnumber=a.blnumber 
left outer join #INLUSD INUS on INUS.blnumber=a.blnumber 
left outer join #ARBUSD ARUS on ARUS.blnumber=a.blnumber 
WHERE     (a.ImportExport = 2) '+ @str + ' order by a.Portofdischarge,a.blnumber asc'
EXEC (@Query)
```

Comment: Not enough information, can you provide table structure and complete set of query? "SELECT     a.PortofDischarge, ....., a.Vessel," is unacceptable. Can you provide query plan as well?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! Look at e.g. your `Sailed_Date` in the temp table - ***WHY*** is this **date** stored as a `varchar`?? Don't do this!! If it's a date - store it in `DATE` or `DATETIME2(N)` !!

Comment: @RawitasKrungkaew I already ran out of maximum length I am not able to post the schema

Comment: Seems to me, that the only difference in the sub-queries loading in temporary tables is `ConfigCode`. Is it possible to rewrite the query into single one using [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.90).aspx)?

Comment: You can use http://sqlfiddle.com/. Anyway, I see you have many temp table with the same structure. Why don't you group #OCF and #DDC into one table and add ConfigCode to differentiate the data. Then in final query, "left outer join #OCF_DDC OC on OC.blnumber=a.blnumber"  and OC.ConfigCode = 'OCF'. You can do the same for other temp table.

Comment: It looks like your table contains more data, so better to create a index on the table so that the query execution becomes faster.

Comment: I also would like to know how is the performance when you run only the query without stored procedure header. If it is faster than running via sp, please take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/30092833/1554116

Comment: @RawitasKrungkaew The performance is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your efforts and time looking into my issue.

The query used to pull all the records from BLMaster without filtering with the parameters passed to the stored procedure.

P.S. Thanks to my vendor.

```
WHERE (a.ImportExport = 2) AND (B.ConfigCode = 'OCF')
/*  Added below two lines to all WHERE clause solved my issue  */
AND a.Vessel = @vessel
AND a.Voyage = @voyage
```

Table BLMaster has around 12lakhs records due to this it was taking so long time.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience
 1) Try to put your parameter into local variable before use.

```
create procedure [dbo].[usp_test](@Id varchar(20))
as
begin
  select * from Test
  where Id = @Id
end
```

**to**

```
alter procedure [dbo].[usp_test](@Id varchar(20))
as
begin
  declare @local_id varchar(20) = @Id

  select * from Test
  where Id = @local_id
end
```

2) Use recompile hint. This will get new query plan which is more suitable for the query based on parameter value.

```
exec dbo.usp_test 1 with recompile
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30092833/1554116