# Stored procedure master.dbo.xp_instance_regread parameter explanation

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to know the definition of a parameter in stored procedure  `master.dbo.xp_instance_regread`.

The stored procedure look like this

```
  DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(4000)

   EXEC master.dbo.xp_instance_regread
       N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
       N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer',
       N'BackupDirectory',
       @path OUTPUT, 'no_output'**--what is this string for?**
   select @path
```

My question is what is the purpose of having a string besides `@path OUTPUT`?

The string I am referring to is 'no_output' in the stored procedure.

Comment: Does it work the same for you without specifying that final parameter?

Comment: Currently if i execute this command with or without the last parameter it work the same because the sql server have value for my backup directory. I suspect the string is act like default return if sql server return nothing from the query, i cant search it online because this stored procedure is undocumented.

Comment: It's difficult because as you say this is an undocumented extended stored procedure and so there's little/no information about the exact parameters which I can find. If you suspect it's a default return value, could you try specifying other parameters which would result in no output to `@path` and see if it instead returns this string?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i try to set my backup directory to empty and run the query with or without the last parameter, both query return null which mean my hypothesis is wrong. I found that i can run the parameter without the last parameter, i really need to know what is the use of the last parameter because i need to deploy this query in my application

Comment: Why exactly do you need to know what this last parameter does? Is the stored procedure not giving you the result you want/need? If you're getting the result you require, then just omit this parameter. This matches most examples online - I only found one with this parameter specified, with exactly the same string you have quoted, so I assume this is where you found it.

Comment: After surfing the internet, I am getting confused about the number of parameters of `xp_instance_regread`, Let say I passed parameters like this `EXEC master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer',N'BackupDirectory',N'111', N'222',N'333', N'444',N'555', N'666',N'777', N'888'` So why there is no error like That: `Procedure or function  has too many arguments specified.` !!

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the final `'no_output'` parameter value is to tell SQL Server to not send [raiserror](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql) or [print](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/print-transact-sql) status messages to registered listeners (e.g., to the SSMS Messages output window or to the [SqlConnection.InfoMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage) event). It has nothing to do with the `@path output` parameter.

For example, if the NumErrorLogs value doesn't exist in the registry, then the following code to read its value will produce an output message:

```
declare @NumErrorLogs int;
exec xp_instance_regread
  N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
  N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer',
  N'NumErrorLogs',
  @NumErrorLogs output
```

That will print this low severity output (e.g., in the Messages tab in SSMS):

```
RegQueryValueEx() returned error 2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.'
Msg 22001, Level 1, State 1
```

However, if we add the magic `'no_output'` literal value as the last parameter, then the behavior is different.

```
declare @NumErrorLogs int;
exec xp_instance_regread
  N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
  N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer',
  N'NumErrorLogs',
  @NumErrorLogs output,
  'no_output'
```

When using `'no_output'` as the last parameter, then no output status message is sent to any listener.

You can use `exec xp_instance_regdeletevalue N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'NumErrorLogs'` to delete the value and try this yourself. Or you can use SSMS > SqlInstance > Management > right-click SQL Server Logs > Configure, uncheck the box for "Limit the number of error log files before they are recycled", then click OK.

FWIW, I stumbled across this question and [a related thread](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/issues/2836#issuecomment-805894152) while searching for how to suppress the  `RegQueryValueEx` message I was seeing in my Messages output.

Regarding the parameter name and ordering, the `xp_instance_regread` extended stored procedure is [undocumented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/general-extended-stored-procedures-transact-sql), and its parameters are positionally bound. You can name the last parameter anything you want (e.g., `@x` or `@no_output`), and it will still work. The parameter binding mechanism for extended stored procedures is different from normal Transact-SQL stored procedures. An extended stored procedure essentially just wraps a call into a function exported from a DLL. For more information, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-stored-procedures-programming/how-extended-stored-procedures-work) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4603497/1882616).